# python: iterate through two objects in a list at once

Tags: python, list, dictionary, iteration

Have a call to an SQL db via python that returns output in paired dictionaries within a list:

```
[{'Something1A':Num1A}, {'Something1B':Num1B}, {'Something2A':Num2A} ...]
```

I want to iterate through this list but pull two dictionaries at the same time.

I know that `for obj1, obj2 in <list>` isn't the right way to do this, but what is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using zip with an iterator over the list:

```
>>> dicts = [{'1A': 1}, {'1B': 2}, {'2A': 3}, {'2B': 4}]
>>> for obj1, obj2 in zip(*[iter(dicts)]*2):
    print obj1, obj2


{'1A': 1} {'1B': 2}
{'2A': 3} {'2B': 4}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) here.

```
>>> testList = [{'2': 2}, {'3':3}, {'4':4}, {'5':5}]
>>> for i, j in zip(testList[::2], testList[1::2]):
        print i, j


{'2': 2} {'3': 3}
{'4': 4} {'5': 5}
```

Alternative (without using `zip()`):

```
for elem in range(0, len(testList), 2):
    firstDict, secondDict = testList[i], testList[i+1]
```

Comment: list slicing makes a whole new list. That is gonna take extra spaces. Better use index. Check my code.

Comment: Your code prints `({'2': 2}, {'3': 3})\n({'3': 3}, {'4': 4})`, you need to change it to `for i in range(0, len(testList), 2): print(testList[i],testList[i+1])`

Comment: oops ! Time to take a nap I guess ! :D You might want to take down your down vote.

Comment: Man ! these guys don't even leave comments why they have downvoted ! anyway @Sukrit thanks for pointing out my bug.

Comment: Suggsestion: perhaps link to the Python 3 docs for zip? https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip

An experienced pythonista might have recognized right away that they were looking at python 2 docs, but I am a n00b and I did not. In case you check this, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> L = [{'1A': 1},{'1B': 1},{'2A': 2}, {'2B': 2}]
>>> zip(*[iter(L)]*2)
[({'1A': 1}, {'1B': 1}), ({'2A': 2}, {'2B': 2})]
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the Python idiom for *grouping* items in an iterable is

```
zip(*[iter(iterable)])*n)
```

Where *iterable* is your list of dictionaries and *n* is 2 if you want them in groups of 2.

The solution would then look like this.

```
>>> data = [{'A':1}, {'B':2}, {'C':3}, {'D':4}]
>>> for dict1, dict2, in zip(*[iter(data)]*2):
    print dict1, dict2


{'A': 1} {'B': 2}
{'C': 3} {'D': 4}
>>>
```

This does not rely on slicing which means it's more memory efficient and likely faster as well since the two sequences that zip is 'zipping' in this case are being generated on the fly via `iter(data)`, meaning *one pass* instead of *three passes* (1 for the first slice, 1 for seconds slice, 1 for zip).

If for some reason your data was very large then you probably wouldn't want to construct a whole new list of tuples which zip returns just to loop through it once. In that case you could use `itertools.izip` in place of `zip`.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html

Look for 'grouper', you'd use n=2.

```
import itertools
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return itertools.izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure he wants (1A, 1B), (2A, 2B), etc., not (1A, 1B), (1B, 2A), etc.

Answer (score 0):

simply

in Python 2

```
li = [{'Something1A':10}, {'Something1B':201}, {'Something2A':405} ]
from itertools import imap
for a,b in imap(lambda x: x.items()[0], li):
    print a,b
```

in Python 3, `map()` is already a generator

Answer (score -1):

Use index to fetch two elements from the list.

```
testList = [{'2': 2}, {'3':3}, {'4':4}, {'5':5}]
for i in range(0,len(testList),2):
    print(testList[i],testList[i+1])
```